# Displaying a set of rows as single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

I have a table with the following rows:

```
MsgID |       DateTime       | State | TimeDiff
---------------------------------------------
387   | 2014-09-06 21:06:27  | 2     | 43
387   | 2014-09-06 21:06:28  | 3     | 44
212   | 2014-09-06 22:16:27  | 1     | 0
212   | 2014-09-06 22:16:38  | 3     | 11
532   | 2014-09-06 23:26:27  | 1     | 0
532   | 2014-09-06 23:27:27  | 3     | 60
532   | 2014-09-06 23:27:28  | 2     | 61
215   | 2014-09-06 23:46:27  | 1     | 0
212   | 2014-09-07 22:16:27  | 1     | 0
212   | 2014-09-07 22:16:37  | 2     | 10
212   | 2014-09-07 22:16:38  | 3     | 11
```

I want to combine these rows like this:

```
MsgID |       State 1       |       State 2       |       State 3       | 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
212   | 2014-09-06 22:16:27 | null                | 2014-09-06 22:16:38 |
532   | 2014-09-06 23:26:27 | 2014-09-06 23:27:28 | 2014-09-06 23:27:27 |
215   | 2014-09-06 23:46:27 | null                | null                |
212   | 2014-09-07 22:16:27 | 2014-09-07 22:16:37 | 2014-09-07 22:16:38 |
```

In this example the rows with MsgID = 387 are left out because they don't have a start condition (state 1).

I have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: Can `State` have a value of `4` or higher? If so, do you need columns for those too? What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can Use PIVOT statement

Answer (score 2):

You can use PIVOT statement in a query like  below.

Please note that you must be familiar with **[PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)** syntax.
The innermost query is used to qualify message ids so that MsgId like 387 are not taken up.
The query right above with `row_number()`s is to help identify gaps. This is a common solution for [gaps-and-islands](/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands) type problem. See a useful link on gaps and islands **[here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/)**

<kbd>**[See working demo](http://rextester.com/TRZ81099)**</kbd>

```
select 
 MsgID,
 State1= [1],
 State2= [2],
 State3=[3]
from 
(
    select 
    t1.MsgID,
    t1.DateTime,
    T1.State,
    r=row_number() over ( order by t1.[DateTime])- row_number() over( partition by t1.MsgID order by t1.[Datetime])
from t t1
join 
(
    select MsgId 
    from t 
    group by MsgID 
    having min(State)=1
) t2
on t1.MsgId=t2.MsgId
) src
PIVOT
(
    max(DateTime) for State in ([1],[2],[3])
    )p
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use difference of `row_numbers` and do the *conditional* aggregation  :

```
select msgid, max(case when state = 1 then datetime end) state1,
              max(case when state = 2 then datetime end) state2,
              max(case when state = 3 then datetime end) state3
from (select *, row_number() over (partition by msgid order by [datetime]) seq1,
                row_number() over (partition by msgid, cast(datetime as date) order by datetime) seq2
      from table t
      where exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.msgid = t.msgid and t1.state = 1)
     ) t
group by msgid, (seq1-seq2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see this as a gaps-and-islands problem.  Simple aggregation by message id and date works for your sample data:

```
select msgid,
       max(case when state = 1 then datetime end) as state1,
       max(case when state = 2 then datetime end) as state2,
       max(case when state = 3 then datetime end) as state3
from t
group by msgid, cast(datetime as date)
having min(t.state) = 1;
```

Note:  This assumes that the minimum state that you could have is "1".  Otherwise, you can use:

```
having sum(case when t.state = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```